# Building python_module_qgis__analysis module

Tags: pyqgis

I am building QGIS code on Windows 11. But I am unable to build 'python_module_qgis__analysis' project. It is always throwing this error "sip-build: 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin\qmake.exe -recursive QGIS.pro' failed returning 3". Other modules like python_module_qgis_core, python_module_qgis__gui etc are getting built.

How do I resolve this?